# Eleventy, gulp and modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, gulp, eleventy

I'm working on a project that uses `eleventy` (v1.0.2) and `gulp` (v4.0.2) with `node` (v16.17.0).

Some of the current versions of the `node` modules that I need to use in my `gulpfile.js` file have now been converted to Javascript modules, and need to be imported with `import` rather than `require`. However, this leads me into a whole world of pain.

`gulp` doesn't seem to be able to cope with ES6 syntax (with `import`) unless I change my `package.json` so that it includes `"type": "module"`. However, that's fatal to `eleventy`, which breaks with:

```
require() of ES Module /Users/user/blahblah/eleventy.js from
/Users/user/blahblah/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/TemplateConfig.js
not supported.
[11ty] .eleventy.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file
whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which
declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
```

The suggested solutions:

```
Instead rename .eleventy.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code
to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, 
or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs"
```

don't seem to be helpful. If I rename `.eleventy.js` to `.eleventy.cjs`, then it becomes invisible to `eleventy`, and changing the `type` in `package.json` back to `commonjs` would just put me back where I was with respect to `gulp`.

I tried renaming `gulpfile.js` to `gulpfile.mjs`, but that doesn't help: `gulp` can't see files with a `.mjs` extension.

One option is to drop the modules I need in my Gulpfile back to older versions that can be imported with `require`, but in some cases the previous versions of the modules are 3 years old. So that doesn't feel like a good solution.

It looks as if I might be able to work around the problem by installing the `babel` transpiler and writing my Gulpfile as `gulpfile.babel.js`. But it seems bizarre to me that in 2022 I still need to use transpilation just to get ES6 syntax; it feels like there should be a better way.

I'd like to future-proof this project as much as possible, so ideally I'd write my Gulpfile in ES6 (and, ideally, all my `eleventy` code as well). But it seems as if this isn't an option currently (unless I use transpilation).

Am I overlooking or misunderstanding something, or are `gulp` and `eleventy` still challenged with respect to modules?

ETA: Transpilation is *not* the answer, because `babel` just helpfully turns each `import` back into a `require`, and the modules that insist on being `import`ed rather than `require`d promptly break.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it turns out that `gulp` is able to handle `.mjs` files without problems, but it is essential to have an up-to-date version of `gulp-cli`.

The solution was to upgrade `gulp-cli` to 2.3.0, then rename my Gulpfile to `gulpfile.mjs` and use ES6 syntax.

There is no need to change the `type` in `package.json` to make this solution work, so `eleventy` is unaffected. Both `gulp` and `eleventy` can then be launched by appropriate `npm` scripts. Thus, for example, I can define:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "gulp; npx @11ty/eleventy",
  "serve": "gulp; npx @11ty/eleventy --serve"
}
```

in my `package.json` and launch a full build with:

```
npm run build
```